# Quotient of Cohen-Macaulay ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Cohen-Macaulay ring, and $I$ an ideal of $A$.
What can we say about $\operatorname{depth}(A/I)$?
I know that $\operatorname{depth}(A/I)\le \dim(A/I)$.

Comment: What would you like to say? You can choose ideals so that the depth can be any number in the allowed range of $[0,\dim (A/I)]$.

Comment: For example, depth(A) -depth(I) less than or equal depth(A/I)???

Comment: No. For example, consider the case of $I$ a maximal ideal. Then depth of $A/I=0$ and if $\dim A>0$ (locally near $I$), the depth of $I=1$. But, depth of $A$ can be as large as you want.

Comment: A is cohen-macaulay, so, dim(A) = depth(A) = depth(I) (because I is a maximal ideal)

Comment: @PauloRossi.  You are wrong to write that $\text{depth}(I)$ equals $\text{depth}(A)$.  If $R$ is a local integral domain, and if $(x,y)$ is any ordered pair of nonzero elements of the maximal ideal $I$, then $\overline{x} \in I/xI$ is nonzero, but $y\cdot \overline{x}$ equals $0$ in $I/xI$.  Thus, the depth of $I$ is at most $1$.

Comment: But I said $R$ is cohen-macaulay ring!

Comment: "But I said $R$ is cohen-macaulay ring!"  I do not know what you are trying to communicate.  I wrote "R" once in my comment when I should have written "A" -- is that your concern?  As demonstrated in my comment, for every local integral domain $A$, including for all Cohen-Macaulay local integral domains, the depth of the maximal ideal, considered as an $A$-module, is at most $1$.

Comment: Now I see, "considered as an $A-$module. Thank you!